# Printing Partitions of a Number Using a Constraint on Values in Partition

Tags: c++, variables

I'm taking a computer science course right now, and one of the questions on my latest assignment is this:

*"A partition of an integer n is a way of writing n as a sum of positive integers. For
example, for n=7, a partition is 1+1+5. Write a program that finds all the
partitions of an integer n using r integers. For example, all the partitions of n=7
using r=3 integers are 1+1+5, 1+2+4, 1+3+3, 2+2+3."*

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple days now, and I have no idea how to do it. I understand I need a recursive function to grab variables, and probably an array or vector to store them, but I don't have the slightest idea where to begin.

I'm not asking for anyone to give me the code for this straight-up, as I want to overcome it myself, but if some more experienced coders could point me the right way that would be extremely welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Tristan

Comment: There are plenty of articles you can read to figure out how to write this. Also, when you ask question on StackOver flow you need to show what you have done so far. Make an effort and when you are stuck ask a question and people will help you.

Comment: "I've been struggling with this problem for a couple days now, and I have no idea how to do it." Hard to show what I've done when I don't know where to start isn't it?

Comment: you can read this: http://www.programminglogic.com/integer-partition-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

The function listed below is not recursive but it efficiently enumerates all partitions of an integer `myInt`, which sizes are `PartitionSize` and whose parts are always `>=MinVal` and `<=MaxVal`.  The parts/elements of each partition are listed in an ascending order (left-to-right) and the partitions themselves are ordered lexicographically (top-to-bottom).

This function uses a std::vector to store each partition, but a fixed size array can be substituted in lieu of that vector in order to facilitate straightforward porting to `plain C`.

I expect, that a recursive function with the same functionality, would have a simpler/shorter code, at the expense of being slower and using more RAM for the stack.

```
void GenPartitions(const unsigned int myInt,
                   const unsigned int PartitionSize,
                   unsigned int MinVal,
                   unsigned int MaxVal)
{
    if ((MaxVal = MaxPartitionVal(myInt, PartitionSize, MinVal, MaxVal)) == 0)
        return;

    if ((MinVal = MinPartitionVal(myInt, PartitionSize, MinVal, MaxVal)) == unsigned int(-1))
        return;

    std::vector<unsigned int> partition(PartitionSize);
    unsigned int idx_Last = PartitionSize - 1;
    unsigned int idx_Dec = idx_Last;    //The point that needs to be decremented
    unsigned int idx_Spill = 0;         //Index where the remainder starts spilling leftwise
    unsigned int idx_SpillPrev;         //Copy of the old idx_Spill for optimization of the last "while loop".

    unsigned int LeftRemain = myInt - MaxVal - (idx_Dec - 1)*MinVal;    //The remaining value that needs to be spilled leftwise
    partition[idx_Dec] = MaxVal + 1;    //Initialize first partition. It will be decremented as soon as it enters the "do" loop.

    //std::cout << std::setw(idx_Dec * 3 + 1) << "" << "v" << std::endl;    //Show the first Decrement Point

    do {
        unsigned int val_Dec = partition[idx_Dec] - 1;      //Value AFTER decrementing
        partition[idx_Dec] = val_Dec;                       //Decrement at the Decrement Point

        idx_SpillPrev = idx_Spill;          //For optimization so the last "while loop" does not do unnecessary work.
        idx_Spill = idx_Dec - 1;            //Index where the remainder starts getting spilled. Before the Decrement Pint (not inclusive)

        while (LeftRemain > val_Dec)        //Spill the remainder leftwise while limiting its magnitude, in order to satisfy the left-to-right ascending ordering.
        {
            partition[idx_Spill--] = val_Dec;
            LeftRemain -= val_Dec - MinVal; // Adjust remainder by the amount used up (minVal is assumed to be there already)
            //std::cout << std::setw(((idx_Spill + 1) * 3) + 1) << "" << "-" << std::endl;  //Show the remainder spillage
        }   //For platforms without hardware multiplication, it is possible to calculate the expression (idx_Dec - idx_Spill)*val_Dec inside this loop by multiple additions of val_Dec.

        partition[idx_Spill] = LeftRemain;  //Spill last remainder of remainder
        //std::cout << std::setw((idx_Spill * 3) + 1) << "" << "*" << std::endl;    //Show the last remainder of remainder

        char a = (idx_Spill) ? ~((-3 >> (LeftRemain - MinVal)) << 2) : 11;  //when (LeftRemain == MinVal) then it computes to 11
        char b = (-3 >> (val_Dec - LeftRemain));

        switch (a & b)  //Switch depending on relative magnitudes of elements before and after the partition[idx]. Cases 0, 4, 8 can never occur.
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3: idx_Dec = idx_Spill;
                    LeftRemain = 1 + (idx_Spill - idx_Dec + 1)*MinVal; 
                    break;

            case 5: for (++idx_Dec, LeftRemain = (idx_Dec - idx_Spill)*val_Dec; (idx_Dec <= idx_Last) && (partition[idx_Dec] <= MinVal); idx_Dec++) //Find the next value, that can be decremented while satisfying the left-to-right ascending ordering.
                        LeftRemain += partition[idx_Dec];

                    LeftRemain += 1 + (idx_Spill - idx_Dec + 1)*MinVal;
                    break;

            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 11:idx_Dec = idx_Spill + 1;
                    LeftRemain += 1 + (idx_Spill - idx_Dec + 1)*MinVal;
                    break;


            case 9: for (++idx_Dec, LeftRemain = idx_Dec * val_Dec; (idx_Dec <= idx_Last) && (partition[idx_Dec] <= (val_Dec + 1)); idx_Dec++)  //Find the next value, that can be decremented while satisfying the left-to-right ascending ordering.
                        LeftRemain += partition[idx_Dec];

                    LeftRemain += 1 - (idx_Dec - 1)*MinVal;
                    break;

            case 10:for (LeftRemain += idx_Spill * MinVal + (idx_Dec - idx_Spill)*val_Dec + 1, ++idx_Dec; (idx_Dec <= idx_Last) && (partition[idx_Dec] <= (val_Dec - 1)); idx_Dec++)    //Find the next value, that can be decremented while satisfying the left-to-right ascending ordering. Here [idx_Dec] == [cur]+1. 
                        LeftRemain += partition[idx_Dec];

                    LeftRemain -= (idx_Dec - 1)*MinVal;
                    break;
        }

        while (idx_Spill > idx_SpillPrev)   //Set the elements where the spillage of the remainder did not reach.  For optimization, going down only to idx_SpillPrev 
            partition[--idx_Spill] = MinVal;    //For platforms without hardware multiplication, it is possible to calculate the expression idx_Spill*MinVal inside this loop by multiple additions of MinVal, followed by another "while loop" iterating from idx_SpillPrev to zero (because the optimization skips these iterations). If, so, then both loops would need to be moved before the "switch statement"

        DispPartition(partition);   //Display the partition ...or do sth else with it           
        //std::cout << std::setw((idx_Dec * 3) + 1) << "" << "v" << std::endl;  //Show the Decrement Points

    } while (idx_Dec <= idx_Last);
}
```

Below is a sample output of this function:

```
SAMPLE OUTPUT OF: GenPartitions(20, 4, 1,10):
1, 1, 8,10
1, 2, 7,10
1, 3, 6,10
2, 2, 6,10
1, 4, 5,10
2, 3, 5,10
2, 4, 4,10
3, 3, 4,10
1, 1, 9, 9
1, 2, 8, 9
1, 3, 7, 9
2, 2, 7, 9
1, 4, 6, 9
2, 3, 6, 9
1, 5, 5, 9
2, 4, 5, 9
3, 3, 5, 9
3, 4, 4, 9
1, 3, 8, 8
2, 2, 8, 8
1, 4, 7, 8
2, 3, 7, 8
1, 5, 6, 8
2, 4, 6, 8
3, 3, 6, 8
2, 5, 5, 8
3, 4, 5, 8
4, 4, 4, 8
1, 5, 7, 7
2, 4, 7, 7
3, 3, 7, 7
1, 6, 6, 7
2, 5, 6, 7
3, 4, 6, 7
3, 5, 5, 7
4, 4, 5, 7
2, 6, 6, 6
3, 5, 6, 6
4, 4, 6, 6
4, 5, 5, 6
5, 5, 5, 5
```

If you want to compile it, the helper functions are below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector> 

unsigned int MaxPartitionVal(const unsigned int myInt,
                             const unsigned int PartitionSize,
                             unsigned int MinVal,
                             unsigned int MaxVal)
{
    if ((myInt < 2)
        || (PartitionSize < 2)
        || (PartitionSize > myInt)
        || (MaxVal < 1)
        || (MinVal > MaxVal)
        || (PartitionSize > myInt)
        || ((PartitionSize*MaxVal) < myInt )
        || ((PartitionSize*MinVal) > myInt))    //Sanity checks
        return 0;

    unsigned int last = PartitionSize - 1;

    if (MaxVal + last*MinVal > myInt)
        MaxVal = myInt - last*MinVal;   //It is not always possible to start with the Maximum Value. Decrease it to sth possible

    return MaxVal;
}

unsigned int MinPartitionVal(const unsigned int myInt,
                             const unsigned int PartitionSize,
                             unsigned int MinVal,
                             unsigned int MaxVal)
{
    if ((MaxVal = MaxPartitionVal(myInt, PartitionSize, MinVal, MaxVal)) == 0)   //Assume that MaxVal has precedence over MinVal
        return unsigned int(-1);

    unsigned int last = PartitionSize - 1;

    if (MaxVal + last*MinVal > myInt)
        MinVal = myInt - MaxVal - last*MinVal;  //It is not always possible to start with the Minimum Value. Increase it to sth possible

    return MinVal;
}

void DispPartition(const std::vector<unsigned int>& partition)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < partition.size()-1; i++)       //DISPLAY THE PARTITON HERE ...or do sth else with it.
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << partition[i] << ",";

    std::cout << std::setw(2) << partition[partition.size()-1] << std::endl;
}
```

P.S.
I was motivated to create this non-recursive function for a microcontroller that had very few bytes of free RAM left for the stack (it had a lot of program memory, though).